# W10 computer office 3 min ahead of time, other PCs are ok

Tags: windows-10, time, date, control-panel, clock

How can I solve that I am the only W10 computer in the room that shows a 3-4 min delay (vs http://www.time.gov/, mobiles and the rest of PCs). It is not a configuration problem, even when I synchronize to time.gov it successfully syncs but maintaining the delay.

After reading I would say this could be caused because I usually don't turn off the computer. But still, this is frustrating and I am also curious about how is that something so simple is so apparently unsolvable.

Comment: Is your machine on a domain?

Comment: No, I do a normal login with a W10 account. W8 computers do use Novell but that's not the case for me or any of the other PCs in the same room

Comment: Did you mean that you sync with time-a.nist.gov and not time.gov? time.gov is not a valid ntp server. Type `w32tm /stripchart /computer:time-a.nist.gov` then try `w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.gov` in command prompt. You'll see that time.gov fails. Perhaps try using a different ntp server? Maybe their service is down if you have used it before.

Comment: Yes, and I've done again with your address and as before 3 min of delay (but the message is that it's successfully sync'ed)

Comment: Indeed, if I try w32tm /stripchart /computer:time-a.nist.gov it also fails, it gives error: 0x80070584, the same error than if I type the second batch of commands

Comment: Try command prompt as admin and `w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual /update` and then `net stop w32time && net start w32time` and finally, `w32tm /resync /force`

Comment: The last command failed: "The computer did not resync because no time data was available"

Comment: Check windows firewall for port 123. Your computer is blocking ntp it looks like. Thats also why stripxhadt

Comment: Strip chart failed

Comment: Could be but I have no access to the firewall (Public institution). The question however is how am I getting a 3 min delay while the 2 computers to my left and right take the right hour? They're using the same internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Set the time in your BIOS.

Start PC (or in your case, restart) > (either Delete, F8 or ESC key. Try more if they don't work) > look for System Time

Then set the time to the current time.

Comment: Yes, but that's workarounding the problem. I can live with a 3 min delay, it's just that I want to understand why is this happening

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it for me.  I also had similar problems with my computers.
in cmd line:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:tic.ntp.telstra.net,0×8, /syncfromflags:manual /update
```